# Cordova Hotspot plugin, API level and android version

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have developed a cordova app that uses [cordova-plugin-hotspot](https://github.com/hypery2k/cordova-hotspot-plugin) (  Cordova 3.4.0 / API Level 19) to activate / deactivate android hotspot. All works fine for android `version <=7.0` but now, using **Cordova 8.00** with `Android 7.1, API level > 19` the hotspot doesn't work.

The hotspot plugin is discontinued.

Does there exist other hotspot plugins I can use?